# Implementing HTTP POST Authentication with Gemini ai through Google Vertex AI using Service Account Credentials in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, chatbot, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I want to add chat features to my existing ReactNative app on the App Store.  Instead of using Gemini via Google's generative AI, I plan to use Gemini via Vertex AI. However,  I have a problem: I don't want to use Vertex AI's client library.(accessible at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vertexai).

Instead, I want to send an HTTP POST Request similar to the Example shown here (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/model-reference/gemini#chat).  The issue I'm facing is finding a key that doesn't expire. I don't want to use the access token provided by cloud auth Because it expires after an hour. I want to use the credentials from the .json file for example. I've tried the following code, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to put credentials like private_key_id, private_key, auth_uri, token_uri, etc.

Code Example:

```
  const response = await axios.post(
    'https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/blue-mag-27271/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-1.0-pro:streamGenerateContent?alt=sse',
    {
      contents: updatedChat,
      generationConfig: generationConfig,
      safetySettings: safetySettings,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        // I dont want to utilize the cloud auth print-access-token as it expires after one hour. I want to utilize the credentials from the .json file for example…
        // Authorization: `Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    },
  );
```

Using the client library, I can pass the “authOptions” object, which contains credentials like  "client_email, private_key”…

Here’s an example:

```
   const authOptions = {
  credentials: {
    client_email: '....',
    private_key:
      '...',
  },
}; 

// and this how it can be added  using the client library

 const vertexAiOptions = {
  project: PROJECT_ID,
  location: LOCATION,
  googleAuthOptions: authOptions,
};
```

**But when using the HTTP POST in vertex , how can I do it ?**

Comment: Are you developing a mobile app? Note: the only long-term credential is an API Key. The Vertex AI does not support API Keys. The service account JSON that you show is for creating OAuth tokens which are only valid for one hour and must be recreated.

Comment: The HTTP POST that you mention requires the HTTP `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header. The token is an OAuth access token. That token is created either via User OAuth or from service account JSON (JWT Assertion exchanged for an OAuth token). Those methods are not safe when performed at the client (mobile, web, etc).